# Human Aggression Detection Community, Competition and dataset

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, convolutional-neural-networks, computer-vision

I'm looking for a community or competition website related to human aggression detection using Deep Learning in a video.
Also, I'm looking for a dataset of human aggression activities.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi and welcome to AI SE! Please, ask just one question per post. If you have 2 questions, ask them in their separate post. Can you clarify why do you need a "_community or competition website related to human aggression detection using Deep Learning in a video_". I suggest you describe your goal and your specific problem more in detail.

Comment: Hey @Keivan I guess *you need some dataset for Human Aggression Activity?* I guess your work would become even better if you comeup with some kind of detail like **Do you consider Aggression Scenes in Movies 'Aggressive according to your definition'?** If yes, there are plenty of them, if no, I've some other methodologies to help you :-)

Comment: Hi @AbhasKumarSinha, I need not only some dataset for Human Aggression Activity but also methodologies and instructions for implementing it with deep learning (3D CNN, etc.). Aggression Scenes in movies are not very good for me. Can you please share your methodologies. My aim is to detect aggressive behavior between 2 persons or a small group of people in surveillance cameras that have a top view.